# How to sum up data in the rendered component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to sum up each multiplication of weights and repeats that belong to the same `trained_at` string. Currently I realize the "grouping" of dates by comparing the current date string with the previous date string in the render part of my component.

In my code example that is fully working you can find a `Sum here` comment, where I want to render the calculation result.

My sample data is coming from Firestore in the real app and does not have that calculation. Thus I need to calculate after fetching the result.

This is what I got rendered:

```
_________________
20200918  |
20        |   12
20        |   12
20        |   12
_________________
20200916  |
15        |   12
15        |   12
15        |   12
________________
```

This is what I want to accomplish:

```
_________________
20200918  |  720  <--
20        |   12
20        |   12
20        |   12
_________________
20200916  |  540  <--
15        |   12
15        |   12
15        |   12
________________
```

And this is my code:

```
import React from "react";

function List() {
  /* Sample Data: */
  const set = [
    {
      id: 1,
      trained_at: "20200918",
      weights: 20,
      repeats: 12,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      trained_at: "20200918",
      weights: 20,
      repeats: 12,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      trained_at: "20200918",
      weights: 20,
      repeats: 12,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      trained_at: "20200916",
      weights: 15,
      repeats: 12,
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      trained_at: "20200916",
      weights: 15,
      repeats: 12,
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      trained_at: "20200916",
      weights: 15,
      repeats: 12,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <table>
      {set.map((row, i) => {
        const previous = set[i - 1] !== undefined ? set[i - 1] : {};
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={row.id}>
            {row.trained_at !== previous.trained_at ? (
              <tr>
                <td>{row.trained_at}</td>
                <td>{/* Sum here */}</td>
              </tr>
            ) : (
              <></>
            )}
            <tr>
              <td>{row.weights}</td>
              <td>{row.repeats}</td>
            </tr>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </table>
  );
}
export default List;
```

Comment: The numbers are confusing. `20 * 12 + 20 * 12 + 20 * 12 = 720` but in your example it says `900`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue! :D I corrected it, so that nobody gets confused. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first re-group the items and calculate the sum, then display them.

```
import React from "react";

function groupAndCalc(data) {
  const map = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const key = item.trained_at;
    let group = acc.get(key);
    if (!group) {
      group = { trained_at: key, sum: 0, items: [] };
      acc.set(key, group);
    }

    group.items.push(item);
    group.sum += item.weights * item.repeats;
    
    return acc;
  }, new Map());

  return Array.from(map.values());
}

function List() {
  /* Sample Data: */
  const set = [
    {
      id: 1,
      trained_at: "20200918",
      weights: 20,
      repeats: 12,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      trained_at: "20200918",
      weights: 20,
      repeats: 12,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      trained_at: "20200918",
      weights: 20,
      repeats: 12,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      trained_at: "20200916",
      weights: 15,
      repeats: 12,
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      trained_at: "20200916",
      weights: 15,
      repeats: 12,
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      trained_at: "20200916",
      weights: 15,
      repeats: 12,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <table>
      {groupAndCalc(set).map((group) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={group.trained_at}>
            <tr>
              <td>{group.trained_at}</td>
              <td>{group.sum}</td>
            </tr>
            {group.items.map((row) => (
              <tr key={row.id}>
                <td>{row.weights}</td>
                <td>{row.repeats}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </table>
  );
}
export default List;
```

Comment: Genius! That's great. Just one thing: The groupAndCalc function inverts the ordering of the set data. How can I avoid that?

Comment: No, it didn't invert things.

Comment: Oh, you mean the train_at group is inverted

Comment: That's unexpected...Let me fix that.

Comment: The set has the 20200918 as first date string. Your code is returning the 20200916 date string first.

Comment: See update, I use `Map` instead of plain object, now the order is right.